What do sewing concerns and tide pole mean?
In https://youtu.be/KxSBHqFgrCw
Starting from 15:50

You've got Elon musk and Trump still out there sewing concerns about
mail in ballots

What does sewing concerns mean? Is it showing concerns instead?
Starting from 16:30

We have one more tide pole that we can show everybody.

What does tide pole mean? Is it tight poll instead?

If those are auto-generated subtitles, they presumably predate current competent AI-based methods - sewing = sowing, mail in ballots = mai-in ballots, tide = tied

I’m voting to close this question because it's about a single case of low quality subtitles

I’m voting to close this question because it's about nonsense in a subtitle / caption.

We loves us some AI.

Don't rely on the captions, they're autogenerated and not accurate.
The first should be "sowing" as in seeds. They're spreading concerns.
The second is "tied poll" - they reference an opinion poll that is showing a tied result.
